# Xdebug PhpStorm : Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '19698'

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

[image]I've applied almost everything from internet but it didn't fixed it. It's not debugging my Laravel app. Here's my `php.ini` conf for xdebug :

```
zend_extension = /home/dev/Downloads/xdebug-2.4.0/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode="jit"
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

Comment: Are you sure the extension is running and enabled? The only thing you need to set is remote_enable to on, and the ide key. Jit means xdebug will only try to connect when an error occurs, are you aware of that? And why are you enabling the profiler?

Comment: Please provide `phpinfo()` output as well as [xdebug log](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log) (if you have configured it then it should tell what's going on in the log). But in general: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: I've added my my phpinfo() picture but it's also contain may things below that. So If you specify section I would upload that one . thanks

Comment: Well, it has to be xdebug section for sure. Also -- what php.ini have you edited exactly (full path please). What xdebug log has to say about it?